# How I can hover two elements at the same time?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I wanna make to hover theese elements at the same time: ..span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link icon-top.. and ..a href="javascript:;" class="link1" This is a text..

Please help me with that.

```js
// Dont run this snippet :) I used it to paste me code  \\
```

```css
.top-part > .top-left-part > ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.top-part > .top-left-part > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.top-part > .top-left-part > ul > li > .link1 {
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.top-part > .top-left-part > ul > li > .link1 {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.top-part > .top-left-part > ul > li > .link1:hover {
    color: #2ECC71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.top-part > .top-left-part > ul > li > .icon-top {
    color: white;
    background-color: #555;
    border-radius: 200px;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 0 2.5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.top-part > .top-left-part > ul > li > .icon-top:hover {
    background-color: #2ECC71;
}
```

```html
<ul>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link icon-top"></span>    
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="link1">
                                info@mccore.ml
                            </a></li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope icon-top"></span>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="link1">
                                Kapcsolat
                            </a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: Have you considered putting the `:hover` on the `li`?

Answer (score 4):

In this case those are the only elements contained within a `li` element. Because of this, you can simply apply the hover styling to the `li`:

```css
.top-part > .top-left-part > ul > li:hover {
  ...
}
```

You can then target the individual elements during the hover by extending your selector to include those:

```css
.top-part > .top-left-part > ul > li:hover > .link1 {
    color: #2ECC71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.top-part > .top-left-part > ul > li:hover > .icon-top {
    background-color: #2ECC71;
}
```